# I want to develop OCR software for my own language

Tags: ocr

I want to develop an OCR software for my own language. I'm from Bangladesh, and I want to develop OCR for Bangali. Please, help me and advice me where to start and how. I will be appropriate your help.

Comment: You can start googling OCR Bangali, then you reach the follow website and join the project  http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-bangla-ocr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an admirable effort and a huge undertaking.  Today, even leading manufacturers of OCR technology struggle with non-separable fonts, where characters in each word are interconnected.  Since there is no character separation, pattern analysis or pixel-based matching is many levels harder compared to languages with separate characters within words.  This would be the hardest part of this development for me.

To start development of OCR system, irrelevant for what language, there are many basics on the subject.  There are different algorithms and approaches to image processing.  Google for it and I am sure hundreds of resources will show up.

If you have a more specific question along the way, I am sure the community will try to help.

Ilya Evdokimov